# Ajax.ActionLink not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I am trying to use Ajax.ActionLink in an MVC4 project. I have included these two in my layout page.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

On my About view I have the following code

```
<h3>Server Time</h3>

<div id="timeDisplay">
    Time shown here
</div>
<div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Click here for time", "ServerTime", new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod="GET", UpdateTargetId="timeDisplay"})

</div>
```

Server time action method just returns the latest time as a long time string
Everything works fine the first but when I click the link a second time nothing happens the Server method is not invoked. I checked with FIDDLER and the Http message is not sent. Is it because it using a cached response. How do I make it invoke the method again

Answer (score 0):

Try decorating your `ActionResult` with `OutputCache(NoStore = true ..`

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult ServerTime()
{
    ...
}
```

Or try using `HttpMethod = "POST"` on your AjaxOptions

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Click here for time", "ServerTime", new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId="timeDisplay"})
```